# Можно ли в aiogram отправить данные, которые заполнил пользователь мне, а сообщение об успешной оплате человеку, который заполнял форму?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram-3.x

```
@dp.message(Order.is_paid)
async def is_paid(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Подтвердить', callback_data='is_paid'))
await state.update_data(paid=message.date.now())
user_data = await state.get_data()
caption = f"Клиент: {user_data['chosen_name']}\n" \
          f"Телефон: {user_data['chosen_phone']}\n" \
          f"Email: {user_data['chosen_email']}\n" \
          f"Локация: {user_data['chosen_location']}\n" \
          f"Время: {user_data['chosen_time']}\n" \
          f"Количество билетов: {user_data['tickets_quantity']}\n" \
          f"Оплачено: {int(user_data['tickets_quantity'][0])*price}₽"
photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
await SendPhoto(photo=photo, caption=caption, chat_id=f'{admin_id}',
                reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))
await state.set_state(Order.admin_return)

@dp.callback_query(Order.admin_return, Text('is_paid'))
async def admin_return(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    gif = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/T8Dhl1KPyzRqU/giphy.gif'
    await SendAnimation(animation=gif, caption='Оплата произведена успешно', chat_id=callback.from_user.id)
    await state.clear()
```

Собственно хотел, что бы после того, как я нажал кнопку подтвердить на своем устройстве, клиент просто получал информацию об успешной оплате. Все прекрасно работает, сообщение с данными клиента мне приходит, а вот обратно отправить сообщение об успешной оплате я не могу. Подскажите, как можно этого добиться, весь интернет облазил, по разному пробовал вытаскивать id но все равно ничего не выходит или это вообще бессмысленно?

Comment: Хотел уточнить, что оплата в этом случае не через телеграмм. Человек просто переводит на карту деньги, присылает скриншот оплаты, я это подтверждаю и ему приходит сообщение о том, что все ок.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, кому будет интересно.
Нужно убрать фильтр на состояние и в chat_id передавать id сохраненный в состоянии и все заработает.

```
@dp.message(Order.is_paid)
async def is_paid(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Подтвердить', callback_data='is_paid'))
await state.update_data(paid=message.date.now())
user_data = await state.get_data()
caption = f"Клиент: {user_data['chosen_name']}\n" \
          f"Телефон: {user_data['chosen_phone']}\n" \
          f"Email: {user_data['chosen_email']}\n" \
          f"Локация: {user_data['chosen_location']}\n" \
          f"Время: {user_data['chosen_time']}\n" \
          f"Количество билетов: {user_data['tickets_quantity']}\n" \
          f"Оплачено: {int(user_data['tickets_quantity'][0])*price}₽"
photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
await SendPhoto(photo=photo, caption=caption, chat_id=f'{admin_id}',
                reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))

@dp.callback_query(Text('is_paid'))
async def admin_return(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    gif = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/T8Dhl1KPyzRqU/giphy.gif'
    await SendAnimation(animation=gif, caption='Оплата произведена успешно', chat_id=telegram_id)
    await state.clear()
```